# list files/folders in owncloud with php curl

Tags: php, curl, owncloud

this is a strange question but following some of the owncloud api and working with curl i can get a json or a xml output with `<url>/cs/v1.php/apps/files_sharing/api/v1/shares`

my question is if files_sharing is the only one app that works or if for example **files** app has another parameters that are not documented.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Share is an API specific just for get the info of the sharing files/folders and also to share them.

To obtain the list of files/folders of a directory you must to use the access through the webdav interface that it is localted under the path remote.php/webdav/ of your server.

For example to get the list of files of the root folder you can use this command:

```
curl -X PROPFIND -u user:password "http://yourserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/"
```

Also you have more http methods to make more things:

- PROPFIND = get the list of files/folders
- MKCOL = create folder
- DELETE = delete file/folder
- MOVE = move or rename a file or folder
- PUT = upload file
- GET = download file

Comment: How do we access the files using PROPFIND in php using curl (or WebDAV client like Sabre)?

Comment: Add: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PROPFIND" ); to your curl set up.

Comment: One extra thing of note is that the Owncloud Share API does not seem to show files that are shared TO YOU by another user.  I had to switch to the OwnCloud WEBDAV interface for that.

Comment: @cardinalPilot You must use the param `?shared_with_me=1`. It is not documented in the official API page.